# SystemInfo.supportsComputeShaders is true in one project while false in another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am willing to use asset store  [360 VR Camera Capture Rig](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/53264) package in unity3d. It works correctly into some project while it showing error in some already created projects and custom error(within code) something like this !

```
 if (!SystemInfo.supportsComputeShaders)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("CapturePanorama requires compute shaders. Your system does not support them. " +
                    "On PC, compute shaders require DirectX 11, Windows Vista or later, and a GPU capable of Shader Model 5.0.");
                return;
            }
```

I am amazed that why [SystemInfo.supportsComputeShaders](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-supportsComputeShaders.html) work in some project and why it is not working in some projects? Is this project specific? but [SystemInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.smartdevice.connectivity.systeminfo(v=vs.90).aspx) document told me that

> Stores device information such as CPU information, battery life,
> amount of memory, and operating system version.

So it basically tell about hardware not project then, why i am getting this error when i use different project?

Comment: Try changing serialization settings to "force text" and then running diff between projects settings of two projects. This could pinpoint clues to the reasons behind this